# RGraph, color of bar not working

Tags: html5-canvas, rgraph

I'm trying to colorize a bar chart, but besides the key gets ok, all the bars show the same color

```
window.onload = function ()
{
    var bar = new RGraph.Bar('canv1', [20,17,13,7,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
        .Set('labels', ['M1','M2','M3','M4','M5','M6','M7','M8','M9','M10','M11','M12','M13','M14','M15'])
        .Set('grouping', 'stacked')
        .Set('gutter.bottom', 250)
        .Set('gutter.left', 100)
        .Set('gutter.top', 20)
        .Set('gutter.right', 100)
        .Set('text.angle', 70)
        .Set('labels.above', true)
        .Set('labels.above.size', 8)
        .Set('ymax', 20)
        .Set('shadow', false)
        .Set('background.grid.autofit.numhlines', 2)
        .Set('numxticks', 15)
        .Set('background.grid.autofit.numvlines', 15)
        .Set('numyticks', 2)
        .Set('ylabels.count', 2)
        .Set('key', ['M1','M2','M3','M4','M5','M6','M7','M8','M9','M10','M11','M12','M13','M14','M15'])
        .Set('colors', ['#0099FF','#006699','#006699','#006699','#006699','#6699FF','#6699FF','#6699FF','#6699FF','#006699','#006699','#006699','#006699','#006699','#006699'])
        .Set('scale.decimals', 0)
        .Draw();
}
```

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
bar.Set('colors.sequential', true);
```